How to find out where our nuget packages are hosted
Just learned about building/converting my code library to a nuget package. OK that was simple. A few right clicks created a nuget package file.
But now I want to publish my nuget on our company's nuget site.
But where is it ? How do I publish to it? All I know is the URL that I use in Tools->Options->Nuget as the source but then how do I upload to it?
The address is in this pattern:
https://tfs.mycompany.com/MyCompany/_packaging/MyTeam/nuget/v3/index.json


Have you tried this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/publish?view=azure-devops

TFS is the old name for Azure DevOps, which is probably the same service you're using to host your git repo. Go there (https://tfs.mycompany.com/MyCompany), and in the menu at the left side near the bottom there is likely an option for "Artifacts" (https://tfs.mycompany.com/MyCompany/_packaging). That's where Azure DevOps keeps their private nuget and npm feeds.
For more specific help you'll probably need to reach out to your company's IT department or one of your teammates.

yep got up to Artifacts.  OK so from this point forward I won't look stupid anymore if I ask them ?

Familiarize yourself with that part of the site. Click the dropdown at the top left to see the various Feeds. There is probably one named for your team. Google things like "Azure DevOps publish to private feed". Most companies prefer to set up a pipeline to publish builds to the feed rather than having developers publish there manually. There are plenty of online tutorials along those lines, but hopefully your company culture is such that if you ask a senior dev "can you walk me through setting up a pipeline to publish this to our private nuget feed" you'll get a positive response.
